# highest weighted path for multiple destinations

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, traveling-salesman, longest-path

I have a directed cyclic weighted graph. I want to find a path with the highest some of weights, in length of X vertices, and I don't care what is the destination. I only want to find the highest cost.

Comment: How large is the graph? How large are the weights? What have you tried?

Comment: Didn't tried any "known" alogrithm, since I could't find anything similar to what I need.
I have few hundred nodes, and each node has ~2-3 vertices.

Comment: And you're only looking for paths, not walks, right? So repetition of vertices is not allowed. (If it was allowed, I'd have an O(E*X) solution, E being the number of edges..) Also, are there any limits on X, or is it anything up to the total vertex count?

Comment: Actually it is aloud, but the weight will be lower on the second visit. X is probably around 10 or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved via dynamical-programming-like algorithm.

As you have only just a few hundreds of nodes and X is round 10. You can assign each node v an array Fv with size X, and Fv[i] represents the maximum cost from the source to the node v with length i.

Let s be the source. Set Fs[0] = 0, and all other Fs[i] = -infinity.

All other arrays are initialized as **-infinity** array.

Now,

> for each node v, do the following update:
>
> Fv[i] = max{Fv[i],  Fw[i-1] + cost(w, v) |  where w is neighbor of v}

repeat above updates for at least X times, and then check  Fv[X] for all v to get the maximum possible value you want.

You can use some extra information to retrieve the path, which should be very easy to do.

Above algorithm is a special case of [Bellman-Ford Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Bellman-Ford algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) to do what you want.